# How to make a background gradient

Tags: html, css, gradient

I need help with a webpage I'm webmastering. Here's some code:

```
<body>
<div class="left">
</div>
```

And here's the css for it:

```
.left {
    position: fixed;
    width:50%;
    height: 100vh;
    top:0;
    background-image: url('../img/plakatm.jpg');
    background-size: 1164px,1000px;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The problem is, that i need to make a gradient at the right edge of it. I can't add the gradient to the image, beacause the .left element changes size on smaller monitors and the gradient would not show up.
Here you can see the full site (It's in polish but you don't need to understand it) [Click here](http://muzaventura.pl/ant2/) to see it.
Thanks.
Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `linear-gradient`, something like below will work for you, better separate it to a separate into a different class, not call it `.left`, I call it `.gradient` in this example:

```css
.left {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  background-image: url('http://weknownyourdreamz.com/images/jungle/jungle-04.jpg');
  background-size: 1164px, 1000px;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.left:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background: white;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="left">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you but I need to still have the image. That means that I want to make a gradient from the image to white on the right side.

Comment: Adam, try this, It's what exactly you want now... I change it to online image, you can change it back to your image

Comment: You can also change it to white or any colour you want, to get feel of gradient to background

Answer (score 0):

There is a css-property for gradients. [That](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) should help.

Comment: Thank you but I need to still have the image. That means that I want to make a gradient from the image to white on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can have background gradient.

```css
.left {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #a18cd1 0%, #fbc2eb 100%);
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
</div>
```

And this is the link where you can find good gradients: https://webgradients.com/

Comment: Thank you but I need to still have the image. That means that I want to make a gradient from the image to white on the right side.